# How to configure Core Plot Data Labels with Bindings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-plot, cocoa-bindings

I'm attempting to set up a pie chart using core plot and bindings.  I can get the chart to display properly using CPTPieChartBindingPieSliceWidthValues

```
[pieChart bind:CPTPieChartBindingPieSliceWidthValues
    toObject:[self sectorAllocation]
       withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.sectorPercentage"
           options:nil];
```

(sectorAllocation is a NSArray Controller)

Similarly I tried bind data labels using CPTPlotBindingDataLabels

```
[pieChart bind:CPTPlotBindingDataLabels
          toObject:[self sectorAllocation]
       withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.sectorName"
           options:nil];
```

(sectorName is a NSString value)

However this doesn't seem to work i receive the following error in the console

> [__NSCFString setShadow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x60800023fb00

It seems it doesn't like a string object, so how would i go about this? and what type of object is it looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding expects an `NSArray` of Core Plot layers (`CPTLayer`), one for each data index. `CPTTextLayer` is a common choice since it displays text, but other layer types are allowed, too.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously Core Plot expects a class, whose instances respond to `setShadow:`. In Cocoa there is only one class afaik: `NSView`. This seems to be a reasonable class for plotting a label.

Additionally you can browse the documentation of Core Plot to find out, whether there is a framework class, that responds to `setShadow:`.

Comment: OK looks like it is looking for a instance of CPTTextLayer, which is a subclass of CALayer.  I suspect I will use NSValueTransformer to convert the NSString instance to a CPTTextLayer instance